# error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-express

I program C# as a hobby and recently decided to start learning the ins and outs of ASP.NET as to expand my skill set. However, I recently been having issues with SQL LocalDB (2014) and the "WingtipToys" project provided by [asp.net](http://asp.net).

As stated in the title, I get this error: error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred (picture provided)

[image]

I have tried the following solutions to rectify this problem:
-Installed SQL Server Express 2014 rather than just the LocalDB

-Restarting the service

-Creating another local db through the command line

-using MSQLLocalDB in my connection string `<add name="WingtipToys" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\wingtiptoys.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`.

-Adding

```
<add name="ASP.NET v4.0" autoStart="true" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0"     managedPipelineMode="Integrated">
<processModel identityType="ApplicationPoolIdentity" loadUserProfile="true" setProfileEnvironment="true" />
```

to the applicationhost.config. I could not find it anywhere either, a quick search on my computer turns this up: [image]
just to be safe, I added it to all of them. However, this did not affect anything. I googled around looking to see if anyone else's was missing, but it seems as though I am the only one with this specific issue.

-Checked to see if `SQL Server Agent (SQLEXPRESS)` was running. (it was)

Is there something I am missing? I don't quite understand why I continually get this error even though I have tried all of the solutions listed. I looked in event viewer, but it didn't give me any information beyond that that the server gave me.

I am running `Windows 10` with `SQL Server Express 2014 x64 with Tools` if that information helps.

Comment: Its not SQL express. Try Source=(localdb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename....etc.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have specified that I can log in to the database easily through Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. It is MSQLLocalDB, it definitely exists as such. I even tried your solution just in case, but that did not work either. Same error.

Comment: If you are connecting to sqlexpress and not localdb then try SQLEXPRESS\MSSQLLocalDB or just .\MSSQLLocalDB. Your instance may not be named that though, look at the status bar of SSMS when you are connected.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/n2qgyNO.png is the connection I am using when using Management Studio. This is what I see when I launch and connect: http://i.imgur.com/EdLcslN.png

Comment: If you're connecting to that then remove the AttachDbFileName from the connection string

Comment: @Crowcoder The problem is, after testing it on my spare laptop, it works exactly as it is supposed to. It is only when I use it on my main work laptop that it gives me error 50. I disabled my firewall to test, as well as uninstall/reinstall SQL Server 2014 Express under the same settings as the spare laptop. It still won't work. This is becoming very frustrating, it doesn't make sense to me why it is working on one but not the other. It is the exact same project and everything. I sync it up using OneDrive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92380/discussion-between-crowcoder-and-chris-altig).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what I did to fix it, but I am almost certain it involved creating the connection in the Server Database. The tutorial I was using didn't go over that part, so I assumed that it wouldn't work. However, it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me.

Go to Tools/Options/Database Tools/click Data connection/Now remove Sql Server Instance Name from Right hand box/click ok.

Then try to add another database:
Open Solution Explorer/Right click on project/Add 
New Item/Select Service-based database/click Add

[image]